# Cannot play specific youtube videos through Youtube API

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The main action of my app (Windows Phone 8.1) requires requesting videos from Youtube playlist and playing them. I've been on it for the past couple of months and until then it was working well. Note : I don't have the "official player" from Youtube since it seems it doesn't exist, but I use the MediaElement
Recently (a week ago) I realized that I couldn't play some of the videos anymore . And after not being able to find anything I come to you guys.

I have no error through the requests to Youtube Api but some videos cannot be played, they just don't start as I get no error since it's not the official player. Thing is I didn't changed anything in the past two months on those requests so I can't understand what changed as I didn't see any update on the Youtube Documentation (or wasn't notified).

I use the Youtube object in the MyToolkit package to get the video url of it

```
YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(videoUrl, YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
```

Which give me [this url which could be expired by the time you read this](http://r5---sn-hgn7zn76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=dur,gcr,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&mime=video/mp4&initcwndbps=1976250&ipbits=0&mv=m&mt=1447888572&ms=au&ip=85.170.8.96&pl=22&mn=sn-hgn7zn76&mm=31&id=o-APAfyproSrF7iTZqk50lG0UAKjVCFheiHluMeAXf1vMi&itag=18&expire=1447910222&upn=E_9R76rWf8M&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&dur=219.776&gcr=fr&source=youtube&lmt=1429501367816922&fexp=9405330,9407535,9408710,9408938,9410705,9413031,9414930,9416126,9417683,9418144,9418185,9418905,9419445,9420452,9421289,9421931,9422596,9422618,9423200,9423510,9423662,9424131,9424512,9424777&key=yt6&signature=18C2B7DC3E16FCB70543C8E43F4F4D036F1228E80.2C386989846F7782797665E46F178482F71916DADA) that just redirects me to a white page instead of the video

I checked if there were some Region/Country lock : null
VideoEmbeddable : true
Licence : Youtube
Privacy : Public

EDIT: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: If people ever come across this question, the issue came from the library used to retrieve the Youtube videos from MyToolKit
[Github Issue link](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/issues/35#issuecomment-174020250)
It should be fixed in the version stated in the link

Comment: I just have to say, Awesome job coming back and answering your question so future users can benefit from it as well. Truly commendable!